# How to implement tabs into a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp, but what I do doesn't work at all, and I can't figure out for the life of me why.

```
    <section id="neighbourhood">
    <h1 style="text-decoration: underline"> Neighbourhood </h1>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="Groceries()" href="#tab1">Groceries</a></li>
    <li id="rtab2"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" onclick="Cafes()">Cafes</a></li>
    <li id="rtab3"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Restuarants</a></li>
    <li id="rtab4"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Health clubs</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>

   <div class="tab-content">
<div  id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <tr>
        <td><h2>Metro</h2><br>
        <p> 2300 Yonge St</p></td>
        <td><h2>Sobeys</h2><br>
        <p>710 Mt Pleasant Rd</p></td>
        <td><h2>Marcheleo's Gourment Marketplace</h2><br>
        <p>181 Eglinton Ave E</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h2>Kenpik Bulk Shop</h2><br>
        <p>151 Manor Rd E</p></td>
        <td><h2>Summerhill Market</h2><br>
        <p>1054 Mt Pleasant Rd</p></td>
        <td><h2>Valu-Mart</h2><br>
        <p>1500 Bayview Ave</p></td>
    </tr>

</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
<tr>
        <td><h2>de Mello Palheta Coffee Roasters</h2><br>
        <p> 2489 Yonge St</p></td>
        <td><h2>La Bohème Café Patisserie</h2><br>
        <p>2481 Yonge St</p></td>
        <td><h2>Istanbul Cafe & Espresso Bar</h2><br>
        <p>174 Eglinton Ave</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h2>Rachel's Coffee house</h2><br>
        <p>2011 Yonge St</p></td>
        <td><h2>Himalayan Java</h2><br>
        <p>2552 Yonge St</p></td>
        <td><h2>Jules Café Patisserie</h2><br>
        <p>617 Mt Pleasant Rd</p></td>
    </tr>

</div>

<div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
</div>

<div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
</div>

 </div>
```

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
      });
     });
     </script>
```

This is for the most part just a copy of the examples in the tutorial, just with my own custom content, however it doesn't work at all and just presents itself as a bunch of div elements stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Looks fine to me. https://jsfiddle.net/bzju5kc6/. Are you importing bootstrap CSS AND bootstrap javascript?

Comment: You should place your code into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Also, at quick glance, it looks like your markup has some issues. `<tr>` tags would go under a `<table>`, not a `<div>`. Looking at @Eric's reply just now, though, it may just be that you forgot to import bootstrap. Any 404's in your console?

Comment: I have bootstrap in the beginning of the page. I didn't include it here but it's there in my code.

Comment: Then you must have extra code that's conflicting with bootstraps css. My jsFiddle used only the given code and bootstraps 2 files, compare it to your code and find the difference.

Comment: I suggest avoiding w3schools.com. They have a lot of information that's inaccurate, outdated, or just poorly written.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because you didn't include Bootstrap, which is a CSS and Javascript library. Try adding those lines in the `<head>` section of your HTML :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Maybe this too --><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I included bootstrap.

Comment: well, I tried your code in w3school Tryit Editor and it worked perfectly. Check you don't have errors in your developper console (Ctrl + Maj + I on Chrome). Sometimes it doesn't accept to load your scripts because they must be loaded over HTTPS and not HTTP protocol. If it's your case, replace `http://` by `https://` in your `script`'s `scr` and in your `link rel="stylesheet"`'s `href`